# Running cumulative return in sql

Tags: sql, return, finance

Looking to have a running cumulative return for a series of daily returns? I know this can be solved using exp and sum, but my return series is not calculated using LN.

Hoping to solve this without using loops, as they are very inefficient in sql.
Its important to make this run fast.

Dataset:

[image]

desired result

[image]

Comment: You now have an opportunity to fix your question so it has useful information.  Sample data, desired results, and SQL you have attempted all make a question better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*,
       (select exp(sum(log(1 + return))) - 1
        from table t2
        where t2.date <= t.date
       ) as cumereturn
from table t;
```

The functions for `exp()` and `log()` may be different in the database you are using.  In many databases, you can also use:

```
select t.*, exp(sum(log(1 + return) over (order by date)) - 1
from table t;
```

I don't think any database has a built in `product()` aggregation function.  Alas.

Answer (score 1):

converting `(1+r)(1+r)(1+r)` to

```
exp(log(1+r) + log(1+r) + log(1+r))
```

does not work because 1+r could be negative. 
Negative log is undefined. i.e. the return is less than -100%

Comment: How would you deal with the negative?

Comment: Tradable products do not go below 0. Recently made false by WTI, but one cannot calculate the return of a product going negative regardless of the method chosen. So yes, you can use logs.