# Calculative cumulative returns using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently generate a user's "monthly_return" between two months using the code below. How would I turn "monthly_return" into a cumulative "linked" return similar to the StackOverflow question linked below?

Similar question: [Running cumulative return in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700772/running-cumulative-return-in-sql)

I tried:

```
exp(sum(log(1 + cumulative_return) over (order by date)) - 1)
```

But get the error:

PG::WrongObjectType: ERROR: OVER specified, but log is not a window function nor an aggregate function LINE 3: exp(sum(log(1 + cumulative_return) over (order by date)) - 1... ^ : SELECT portfolio_id, exp(sum(log(1 + cumulative_return) over (order by date)) - 1) FROM (SELECT date, portfolio_id, (value_cents * 0.01 - cash_flow_cents * 0.01) / (lag(value_cents * 0.01, 1) over ( ORDER BY portfolio_id, date)) - 1 AS cumulative_return FROM portfolio_balances WHERE portfolio_id = 16 ORDER BY portfolio_id, date) as return_data;

The input data would be:

```
1/1/2017: $100 value, $100 cash flow
1/2/2017: $100 value, $0 cash flow
1/3/2017: $100 value, $0 cash flow
1/4/2017: $200 value, $100 cash flow
```

The output would be:

```
1/1/2017: 0% cumulative return
1/2/2017: 0% cumulative return
1/3/2017: 0% cumulative return
1/4/2017: 0% cumulative return
```

My current code which shows monthly returns which are not linked (cumulative).

```
SELECT 
date,
portfolio_id,
(value_cents * 0.01 - cash_flow_cents * 0.01) / (lag(value_cents * 0.01, 1) over ( ORDER BY portfolio_id, date)) - 1 AS monthly_return
FROM portfolio_balances
WHERE portfolio_id = 16
ORDER BY portfolio_id, date;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Thanks, Postgres!

Comment: show some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: @vkp - Thanks. Let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cumulative sum:

```
SELECT p.*,
       SUM(monthly_return) OVER (PARTITION BY portfolio_id ORDER BY date) as running_monthly_return
FROM (SELECT  date, portfolio_id,
              (value_cents * 0.01 - cash_flow_cents * 0.01) / (lag(value_cents * 0.01, 1) over ( ORDER BY portfolio_id, date)) - 1 AS monthly_return
      FROM portfolio_balances
      WHERE portfolio_id = 16
     ) p
ORDER BY portfolio_id, date;
```

I don't see that this makes much sense, because you have the cumulative sum of a ratio, but that appears to be what you are asking for.

Comment: How would you multiply the values together rather than take the sum?